# printing results in stdout file as well as console

Tags: python, logging, printing, python-2.6

My requirement is to print the output of the file in the console as well as a log file. The following piece of code does it for me , exept for a minor hiccup. I am calling a perl script at the end of the file , whose output is getting displayed in the console , but not getting printed to the file.

```
import subprocess
import sys
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)

f = open('MyFile.txt', 'w')
original = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, f)
print "Logging Started"
# My code
print "A"

subprocess.call(['./MyScript])
sys.stdout = original
print "Logging Stopped"  # Only on stdout
f.close()
```

Can anyone please advise how can that be achieved? Or is it possible at all to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
print subprocess.check_output(['./MyScript])
```

In Python 2.6, either use the backport [`subprocess32`](http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/), or copy the [2.7 source for `check_output`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l544).

Comment: `print subprocess.check_output(['./MyScript'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'`

Comment: Python 2.6.4, sorry for the confusion. WIll remove the tag.

Comment: @misguided, if you click through the link to the docs, you can see that it was added in Python 2.7, which is what you tagged the question with

Comment: If you're not on 2.7, use the [subprocess32](http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/) backport (which, as the name implies, also gives you the 3.2 improvements to `communicate`, etc.… although not the 3.3 improvements, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `check_output` is implemented in Python2.7, you should be able to work out how to use `subprocess.Popen`

```
def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    if 'stdout' in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code did the trick for me. Thanks everyone for helping.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
import sys
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)

f = open('MyFile.txt', 'w')
original = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, f)
print "Logging Started"
# My code
print "A"

def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        error = subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
        error.output = output
        raise error
    return output

location = "%s/folder"%(os.environ["Home"])
myoutput = check_output(['./MyFile'])
print myoutput
sys.stdout = original
print "Logging Stopped"  # Only on stdout
f.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
subprocess.check_ouput
```

is introduced in python 2.7, if you can onlu use previous versions, you can just use the Popen and set the stdout to your output stream (but in your case, you already overrided the sys.stdout, I think it's not needed), just change to:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['./MyScript'])
```

Comment: Doesn't give the required output. ALso the unix (SSH) window where I am running the script hangs after running the `MyScript`

Comment: This isn't a complete solution; just creating a `Popen` doesn't do any good unless you also pass it the a `stdout` pipe, read from it, and `poll` or `wait` the process (or merge the latter two into `communicate`).

Comment: @abarnert you mean `session = subprocess.Popen(['./MyScript'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)` . Not sure what to do from here though

Comment: @misguided: I wouldn't pipe `stdin` and `stderr`; that just makes it more complicated. Anyway, what you do from there is… exactly what's in the source to `check_output` that Ashwini's answer and my comment link to, and that gnibbler's answer copies directly: `output, _ = p.communicate(); ret = p.poll(); if ret: raise soemthing`.